# Fiber bundle orientability vs manifold orientability

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I read this question about vector bundles

[Bundle orientability vs manifold orientability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50809/bundle-orientability-vs-manifold-orientability)

In the answer to this question the last sentence states the following (I think fairly well known) result about vector bundles

"Let E be a vector bundle over M. Consider the statements (i) M is orientable as a manifold (ii) E is orientable as a manifold (iii) E is orientable as a vector bundle. Any two of the statements being true will imply the third."

I am curious if this statement generalizes to all fiber bundles with orientable fiber.

In other words, is it true that: **Let $ F \to E \to M $ be a fiber bundle over M, with $ F $ an orientable manifold. Consider the statements (i) M is orientable as a manifold (ii) E is orientable as a manifold (iii) E is orientable as a fiber bundle. Any two of the statements being true will imply the third.**

If not, is a similar 2-out-of-3 theorem true for sphere bundles or some other more restricted class of fiber bundles?

Some stuff that I tried (focused on circle bundles in which case the bundle being orientable is equivalent to it being $ U_1 $ principal see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144092/is-every-orientable-circle-bundle-principal)(Note that this is a complete list of all circle bundles over $ S^1,S^2,T^2,K^2,\mathbb{R}P^2 $):

Base $ S^1 $:

- All three:  $ S^1 \to T^2 \to S^1 $ (in general any trivial bundle $ S^1 \times M $ for any orientable manifold $ M $ has base, bundle and total space all orientable)
- Only base orientable: $ S^1 \to K^2 \to S^1 $ where $ K^2 $ is the Klein bottle.

Base $ S^2 $:

- All three: The lens spaces $ S^1 \to L_{n,1} \to S^2 $, where $ n $ is the Euler class of the bundle (for small values of $ n $ we have $ L_{0,1}= S^1 \times S^2, L_{1,1}\cong S^3, L_{2,1}\cong \mathbb{R}P^3 $). $ E^1 \times S^2 $ geometry for $ n=0 $, $ S^3 $ geometry otherwise.

Base $ T^2 $:

- All three: The circle bundles $ S^1 \to MT(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & r \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}) \to T^2 $ where $ MT(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & r \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}) $ denotes the mapping torus of $ T^2 $ corresponding to the mapping class $ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & r \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $, which is the $ r $th power of the Dehn twist $ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $. For $ r=0 $ this is $ T^3 $ and admits $ E^3 $ (flat) geometry while for $ r \neq 0 
   $ these are the nilmanifolds $ N_r $ described in [Is every Nil manifold a nilmanifold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4367670/is-every-nil-manifold-a-nilmanifold) and they admit Nil geometry. $ E^3 $ geometry for $ r=0 $ otherwise Nil geometry.
- Only base orientable: $ S^1 \rtimes_b T^2 $ two of the four flat compact non orientable three manifolds. For $ b=0 $ this is $ S^1 \times K^2 $ with first homology $ \mathbb{Z}^2 \times C_2 $, for $ b=1 $ this is the mapping torus of the Dehn twist diffeomorphism of $ K^2 $ with first homology $ \mathbb{Z}^2 $. The total space is not orientable. These coincide with the two $ U_1 $ principal bundles over $ K^2 $. $ E^3 $ geometry.

Base $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $:

- Only bundle orientable: $ S^1 \to S^1 \times \mathbb{R}P^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^2 $. (in general any trivial bundle $ S^1 \times M $ for any non orientable manifold $ M $ has only the bundle orientable). $ E^1 \times S^2 $ geometry.
- Only bundle orientable: $ S^1 \to (S^2 \times S^1)/(-1,-1) \to \mathbb{R}P^2 $. This is the mapping torus of the antipodal map of $ S^2 $. It is the unique nontrivial $ U_1 $ principal bundle over $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $. $ E^1 \times S^2 $ geometry.
- Only total space orientable: $ S^1 \to P_{4n,1} \to \mathbb{R}P^2 $ where $ P_{4n,1} $ is the standard prism manifold with $ 4n $ element dicyclic fundamental group. $ S^3 $ geometry.
- Only total space orientable: $ S^1 \to UT(\mathbb{R}P^2) \cong L_{4,1} \to \mathbb{R}P^2 $, the unit tangent bundle of $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $. $ S^3 $ geometry.
- Only total space orientable: $ S^1 \to \mathbb{R}P^3 \# \mathbb{R}P^3 \to \mathbb{R}P^2 $. $ E^1 \times S^2 $ geometry.

Base $ K^2 $:

- Only the bundle is orientable: The two principal $ U_1 $ bundles over $ K^2 $ coincide with the two non principal $ S^1 $ bundles over $ T^2 $. These are two of the four non orientable compact flat three manifolds they can also be viewed as two of the four mapping tori of $ K^2 $. $ E^3 $ geometry.
- none of 3: The other two of the four non orientable compact flat three manifolds, they can also be viewed as the other two of the four mapping tori of $ K^2 $. They are non principal bundles $ S^1 \to S^1 \rtimes_b K^2 \to K^2 $ both with non orientable total space. For $ b=0 $ this is the mapping torus of the Y homoeomorphism of $ K^2 $, it has first homology $ \mathbb{Z}^2 \times C_2 \times C_2 $. For $ b=1 $  this is the mapping torus of $ K^2 $ for the mapping class corresponding to the combination of a Dehn twist and a Y homoemorphism. It has first homology $ \mathbb{Z}^2 \times C_4 $. $ E^3 $ geometry.
- Only total space orientable: The circle bundles $ S^1 \to MT(\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -r \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}) \to K^2 $ where $ MT(\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -r \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}) $ denotes the mapping torus of $ T^2 $ corresponding to the mapping class $ \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -r \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $. These manifolds are double covered by $ MT(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2r \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}) $. For $ r=0 $ this is the unit tangent bundle of the Klein $ UT(K^2) $, which admits $ E^3 $(flat) geometry, while for $ r \neq 0 
   $ these admit Nil geometry. $ E^3 $ geometry for $ r=0 $, Nil geometry otherwise.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you think of any potential counterexamples to test?

Comment: @Kajelad I added some examples, I think they all confirm this 2 out of 3 pattern. Unless maybe lens space are a counterexample, do you know if lens spaces are $ U_1 $ principal bundles?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171567/orientability-of-the-total-space-of-a-vector-bundle-and-total-space-of-its-spher/2199740#2199740).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm late to the party, though I wanted to share a quick proof using differential geometry.

Let $F$ be an orientable, connected manifold.

Any fiber bundle $F\hookrightarrow E \overset{\pi}{\to} B$ admits a connection  (see for example [here](https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/%7Ewendl/pub/connections_chapter3.pdf)) this is just a splitting of the tangent bundle of the total space  $TE\simeq H\oplus V$  where $V = \ker d\pi$ is the vertical subbundle (given by $\pi$) and $H$ is the horizontal subbundle (what gives the connection).
*Any fiber bundle admits a connection*, so we pick one and compute the first Steifel-Whitney class*:
$$ w_1(TE)= w_1(H) + w_1(V) = \pi^*(w_1(TB))+ \pi^*(w_1(E))= \pi^*( w_1(TB)+ w_1(E))\in H^1(E;\mathbb Z/2) $$

where we used the isomorphism $H \overset{d\pi}{\to} TB$ implying that $w_1(H)=\pi^*(w_1(TB))$ and that the obstruction to orient the bundle $\pi^*(E)\to E$ is $w_1(V)$ (see **)

Corollary:
i) if $B$ is orientable then the total space $E$ is orientable (as manifold) iff the bundle $E\to B$ is orientable.

ii) if $B$ is not orientable, i.d. $w_1(TB)\neq 0$, then $E$ is orientable (as manifold) iff   $w_1(E) = w_1(TB)$ (note that $\pi^*: H^1(B; \mathbb Z/2) \to H^1(E; \mathbb Z/2)$ is injective because $\pi_1(E)\to \pi_1(B)$ is surjective, abelianization is right exact and $Hom(\cdot, \mathbb Z/2)$ is left exact).

*To avoid confusion, I will **AVOID** the shorthand notation $w_1(X) \sim w_1(TX)$, so when I write $w_1(\xi)$, it is clear that   $\xi$ is a bundle.

** If $E$ is vector bundle we have that $\pi^* E \simeq V$. For a general fiber bundle, notice that  if $\gamma\subset E$ is a loop, and I want to check if the bundle given by $\bigcup_{t} E|_{\pi(\gamma(t))}\to \mathbb S^1$ is orientable, then (since $F$ is orientable and connected) this is the same as checking what happens at a tangent space to the fiber at one point (does the monodromy reverse the orientation?) but this is exactly the same as looking at the monodromy of $\gamma^*(V)\to \mathbb S^1$.